# How do I adjust the pointer speed and scrolling speed of a trackpad?

Tags: scrolling, pointers, magic-trackpad

How can I increase the pointer speed and scrolling speed of Apple Trackpad beyond the max speed allowed in System Settings?  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.01.

Please see below the mouse and trackpad settings

[image]

[image]

Also I have installed the package `kde-config-touchpad` and **not** installed `utouch`. I have used [this](http://indexoutofboundsexception.wordpress.com/) blog for doing so.

[image]

Comment: There is no option to adjust scrolling speed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the only way I can think of that *might* change pointer speed beyond the default allotment.  It might not work.

Install `dconf` editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Run `dconf-editor` and navigate to:

```
org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> peripherals -> touchpad
```

There you can play around with the value of `motion-acceleration`.   The max value that System Settings gives is 10, so maybe setting it to 20 would work.

[image]

Comment: I tried to do it [manually via command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-can-i-set-mouse-sensitivity-not-just-mouse-acceleration) by changing the xinput configuration file, but it kept on reverting to the default settings. Now I am using dconf and it works. The strange part is the change made at dconf doesn't reflect back on the xinput config file. Is it strange or dconf works differently?

Comment: What do I do if there is no "touchpad" option under peripherals?

Comment: @Steve what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Seth I'm running 16.04

Comment: Same here, 16.04LTS, no touchpad under settings-deamon. Found one under desktop though, gonna try that.

Comment: Nope, values dont seem to affect anything. Even after reboot.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus No "Touchpad" under peripherals. Tried desktop one but didn't work.

Comment: @Rahul what version?

Comment: @Seth Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, Gnome

Comment: @Rahul Try the speed key at `org -> gnome -> desktop -> peripherals -> touchpad` and let me know if that works.

Comment: @Seth Didn't work. However `xset m` command seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open System Settings.
2. Click Mouse and Touchpad
3. Increase Acceleration.

also see [Configure mouse speed (not pointer acceleration!)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration)

Comment: Please see the images for the present settings. 1. There is no setting for wheel speed of mouse. 2. The pointer speed of trackpad is miserable (almost making it useless) and there is no threshold control in the trackpad.