# Logitech M560 scrolling is more sensitive in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, logitech, mouse-scroll

After upgrading to 15.04, my (already sad and semiworking) Logitech M560 mouse is not working as in 14.10. The problem is that the scrolling is more sensitive than in the previous release.

Is there a way to fix it? I can't find support for it. (Also, can't bind the keys, but probably that is another question.)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "sensitive"? "Sensible" means "making sense". Anyway, have you check `Settings>Input Devices>Touchpad`?

Comment: Yes, sensitive. And there is no configuration there for the mouse.

Comment: OK. Try this. Run `sudo apt-get install kde-touchpad` and then search `Touchpad` in Unity Dash. This should give you more options. Also look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254847/how-do-i-adjust-the-pointer-speed-and-scrolling-speed-of-a-trackpad.

Comment: I installed it, but it doesn't have the options. See the image above.

Comment: Wrong program. Hold on, I'm going into to Unity to try it out.

Comment: OK. Install KDE System Settings, open that from the Dash and go into Input Devices.

Comment: It is empty when I go to Input Devices

Comment: Make sure this is installed: `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-utopic`.

Comment: That package doesn't exist

Comment: Try with `vivid` on the end.

Comment: No options for autocomplete. Also, I'm using unity, does that makes any difference?

Comment: No, that shouldn't. Search the package name, excluding `utopic`, in the Software Center.

Comment: @Zacharee1, How is installing a **touchpad** driver going to fix a mouse problem?

Comment: What's the output of `synclient -l`?

Comment: get a new mouse?

Comment: @Fabby the result of `synclient` is [this](http://pastebin.com/BivQTbBV)

Comment: @adn: Can you go to a terminal and type: `synclient HorizHysteresis=16&&synclient VertHysteresis=16` If that doesn't help much, double the values and keep doubling them until it gets to the sensitivity you need.  If the sensitivity suddenly becomes too high, go back to the previous setting.  Then report back and I'll give you the perfect answer!  **;-)**

Comment: M500 is really proper working and not too much expensive like gamer mouses but with 5 buttons it already has 10 functions possibilitites ... ?! I only dont know if rubber is fitting to any skin (on hand) cause to mine hand this rubber is sometimes "stabbing" ?! + (deactivated sour) scorpion mouse ?! could this be ?!

Answer (score 1):

Some thing you can try to make the mouse show up in system settings:

- Change USB port of receiver
- Turn mouse off and on again

## Manage logitec unified receiver devices

[Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) is a program to manage logitech unified receiver devices. You can install it using following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel.pavel/solaar
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solaar
```

Unplug the receiver, plug it back in, and start Solaar. You should be able to see the device and change some of its options.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620356/reduce-mouse-sensitivity-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Is M560 supported? I can't find the device in the [list](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/devices.html)

Comment: @A.B. Good question. No idea. I tested it on my device and it worked, but my device is listed..

Comment: @A.B. [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/620382/172367) seems to suggest it works...

Comment: Ok, I can see it. +1