# Reduce mouse sensitivity (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: mouse, 15.04

Didn't have that problem with 14.10 but on a fresh install of 15.04 (Asus N550JV), I found the scrolling button WAY too sensitive.

With the touchpad actived or deactivated, it makes no difference, scrolling precisely with the mouse is awful and just impossible. The mouse is a Logitech M560. It is a few months old and had no trouble on 14.10 and doesn't have any trouble either on W8 (dual boot).

I checked the system settings but there is nothing to set the mouse scrolling speed (but there is a slider for the mouse double click speed and another one for the cursor speed on the touchpad).

Any help appreciated, thank you guys.

Eric

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install systemsettings kde-touchpad`. Run `systemsettings` to open the KDE settings pane. From here, go into Input Devices. The KDE settings app has more options.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Done that. But the systemsettings5 app seems a bit messy (doesn't find the right icons and possibily other stuff). However, it does run, even if it looks a bit weird and empty BUT it seems it detected only one device : the touchpad.

Comment: Really? There are a few tabs. Make sure the Mouse tab is selected.

Comment: No visible tabs. Only a few 'text' menu entries : Overall, configuration, help, Quit. Nothing helpful. I guess some libs are missing...

Comment: Maybe just go ahead and install `kubuntu-desktop`. You don't have to use it.

Comment: Well I installed kubuntu-desktop and ran again systemsettings5. This time, everything looked okay. However there is only one available setting about the mouse scrolling wheel: the number of lines. Changed it from 3 to 1. No change :-/

Answer (score 1):

Okay. It's fixed now.

I read somewhere on askubuntu (sorry didn't save the link :p) there is a known issue with some logitech devices using the unifying receiver. I read that some users fixed some issues changing the usb port the receiver was plugged in. It did not work for me. But what worked was to turn off and back on the mouse lol

And for those who still have some issues, there is also an application that might help (specifically for logitech devices using unifying receivers), it's called solaar. Here is the link: http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/