# System setting that control trackpads

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, touchpad, multi-touch

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 and installed budgie on it , but then just used the classic DE, Then after installing Ubuntu 18.04 on the same machine in a separate drive, i noticed that the trackpad was a lot more responsive in 16.04. In 18.04 it sometimes glitches out and scrolling doesn't work perfectly. My 18.04 installation is vanilla.
My trackpad is : `ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad`
What settings or software packages could influence the trackpad and how do i check?
I need the settings or apps that modify multi touch behaviour.
Since the trackpad feels diffrent in diffrent distros.
The setting menu isn't them same for both Ubuntu versions.The 16.04 installation had quite alot of DE's installed and other packages so i cant remember which one improved the trackpad response over the vanilla 18.04.
Please excuse my terrible English and noobiness in linux.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I adjust the pointer speed and scrolling speed of a trackpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254847/how-do-i-adjust-the-pointer-speed-and-scrolling-speed-of-a-trackpad)

Comment: How is that the same? i am asking about the general feel of it and multi touch not just pointer speed

Comment: The question title is "System setting that control trackpads" and the link is to a question detailing how to access your system settings to control trackpads. Are there specific settings you want to access which are not covered in the answers? If yes, please edit your question to focus only on those.