# Change mouse speed

Tags: xorg, mouse, settings

I would like to change the ratio between the pointer speed and the mouse speed.

Changing the sensitivity and the acceleration is not what I'm looking for:

- sensitivity is something like the threshold of speed above which the pointer starts to accelerate
- acceleration is the magnitude of this acceleration

but what I would like is different : I would like to change the speed of the pointer.

I've looked everywhere but I cannot find a solution to my question. I found something about the xorg.conf (don't even konw if it will work) but I cannot find my xorg.conf.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: First a word of warning: Playing with xorg.conf can easily make your GUI unusable, so before you do something with it, make sure that you know how to revert your changes using command line only. You can place parts of an xorg.conf in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d folder (see `man xorg.conf.d`). Some examples can be found at the Gentoo Xorg documentation: http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/xorg-config.xml#doc_chap4 . To find out details about your mouse (like: what device to use, which driver,...) read /var/log/Xorg.0.log - that should give you some hints...

Comment: @soulsource : / $ sudo find . -name  "xorg.conf" gives nothing ....

Comment: Per default there is no xorg.conf on Ubuntu. It should nevertheless be used, if you create it. In addition, any file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ will be read, in lexicographic order. You can therefore put the relevant InputDevice section in a text file and save it, let's say, as /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-mousesettings.conf

Comment: Oh, btw, I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration - maybe this is of help to you?