# Kubuntu: disable mouse acceleration and adjust mouse speed

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, kde

I would like to disable mouse acceleration. I don't like it when the same physical distance traveled by the mouse results in different screen distance depending on how quickly you move the mouse.

Also, I would like to adjust cursor speed to my liking.

The problem is that Kubuntu doesn't seem to allow either:

[image]

Mouse acceleration cannot be set to `0` and there's not an option for mouse speed/sensitivity.

So, the questions are:

1. How do I disable mouse acceleration completely?
2. How do I adjust mouse speed?

Comment: Same kind of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to adjust mouse speed in KDE

- without enabling mouse acceleration
- and only using the settings dialog (no console, no config files)

This is a colloquial summary of [exhuma's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/192382/128252), don't forget to upvote it.

In KDE, mouse acceleration is not logarithmic. That is, it has two constant mouse speeds: non-accelerated and accelerated. It switches from one to another when you jerk the mouse quickly enough.

The first speed is non-configurable (at least, from GUI). The second speed is configurable.

The solution is:

1. Set "Pointer threshold" to 0. As a result, the second speed will be applied at all times.
2. Adjust "Pointer acceleration" to make that speed higher or lower.

You will end up with a constant, non-dynamic cursor speed adjusted to your liking.

Comment: This answer (point 1 at least) is wrong, unfortunately. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration

Answer (score 2):

In this dialog, to disable the acceleration, you shouldn't set it to 0, rather set it to 1.

Comment: What does a value less than 1 mean then? According to logic, it should result in deceleration but it does not.

Comment: It does acceleration of small movements, instead of acceleration of fast movements what it normally does. Set the acceleration to 0.1, move mouse slightly, and the pointer leaps to an edge of the screen. I don't know why KDE devs thought this may be useful.