# Disable mouse move without disabling click and scroll?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

Is it possible to disable mouse move without disabling click and scroll? I want to make mouse pointer freeze at a point but click and scroll using wheel should work.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `xinput` command that manipulates X devices, whose list can be obtained with

```
  xinput --list
```

Henceforth `id=10` for the mouse assumed, that is [seemingly true for modern Xorg releases](https://askubuntu.com/a/262891/439832).

## Solution [(using property names)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-can-i-set-mouse-sensitivity-not-just-mouse-acceleration/90585):

`xinput set-prop 10 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 65535`

### Return to normality:

`xinput set-prop 10 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1`

> 

## Solution (using property numbers):

```
  xinput list-props 10
```

Find
`Device Accel Constant Deceleration (`*p*`):`
in the output listing, where *p* is a decimal number. Now substitute it into:
 `xinput set-prop 10`*p*`65535`

### Return to normality:

`xinput set-prop 10`*p*`1`

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the game, but the low-tech solution here is to put a bit of tape over your mouse light. That will "disable" the pointer but keep the buttons active, and doesnt mess around with the xinput settings.