# Permanent mouse speed change in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

The topic [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows how to successfully change the speed of the pointer. For example, in my case the solution has been `xinput set-prop 13 276 0.7`. However, the configuration is lost with the restart of the pc. How to make this change permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be adding the command to Startup application, first we'll wrap the command with bash script.

```
touch speedmouse.sh
```

Then, append your command:

```
echo "xinput set-prop 13 276 0.7" >> speedmouse.sh
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gnome-session-properties` to launch startup application. Press <kbd>Add</kbd> to create new startup:

[image]

[image]

You should all set now.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that for me both the device number (of my mouse) and property number (of the sensitivity) seem to change intermittently. EDIT: Nevermind, I realized you can refer to both by name rather than number, so for me it's `xinput set-prop "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" ...`