# How can I change mouse sensitivity using a GUI/slider?

Tags: mouse, kde, gui, xinput

I find it rather tiring when there is no mouse speed setting. The only solution that worked for me is https://askubuntu.com/a/569345/196639

```
xinput list #get device ID
xinput list-props <device-id> #get Coordinate Transformation Matrix (<prop-id>)
xinput set-prop <device-id> <prop-id> <3x3 matrix>

#e.g. (for 0.2x speed)
xinput set-prop 10 154 \
                0.2 0.0 0.0 \
                0.0 0.2 0.0 \
                0.0 0.0 1.0
```

This is rather cumbersome. Is there some program I can install that gives me a mouse sensitivity slider that persists across reboots?

(I'm using KDE, but answers for all environments/WMs are welcome)

For reference, this is the usual interface, with no speed/sensitivity option:
[image]

Comment: Just go through settings and preferences then mouse

Comment: @NerdOfCode unfortunately there are no sensitivity/speed options. I'll add an image.

Comment: Are you sure. On my Mint distribution there are?

Comment: There's acceleration, which doesn't seem to do anything and even if it did I despise non-linear mouse movement (but can understand it's useful for low DPI or with limited desk space).

Comment: Check general...

Comment: No luck either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GP2y.png

Comment: oh sorry. I think I was looking at touchpad

Comment: The mouse is a device specifically designed for interacting with GUIs, and nobody has made a GUI for changing the most basic settings. It's absolutely ridiculous.