# How to set/change i3wm mouse speed (not acceleration)

Tags: 20.04, i3-wm

When I run `xinput list-props 12` (12 is the id for 'Touchpad'), I get the following:

```
Device Enabled (145):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (147): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (282):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (283):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (284):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (285):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (286):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (287): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (288): 3
    libinput Accel Speed (289): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (291):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (292):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (293):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (267): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):    0, 0
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (296):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (297):   1
```

I have ran `xinput --set-prop 12 'libunput Accel Speed' 0.1` to change its acceleration, but that isn't quite what I want - I want to adjust the touchpad's *speed*.

I am not being show the property ID for `Device Accel Constant Deceleration`, which is what I would like to change following the comments on this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration).

Is there something something else I can do to adjust the touchpad speed, not the acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

the setting you are looking for is the
`Coordinate Transformation Matrix`

You can use the default Value
`1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000`

and change the last value.
You can do it like this:

```
ctmVal=3
xinput set-prop 12 "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, $ctmVal
```

the higher `$ctmVal` in this case, the slower the mouse speed