# Where are the mouse button settings in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, configuration

I had my Evoluent VerticalMouse set up to work using HAL FDI files in Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 and before. However, these no longer are respected by Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 so what configuration files are being used instead? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer to this post:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/8506/decrease-mouse-sensitivity-below-the-standard-limit

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with exactly the same mouse.
For now I am typing

**xinput set-button-map NUM 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**

in the terminal.

To find out the value for NUM, type

**xinput list**

This will give you back full functionality.
However, you'll have to do that after every login so it annoys a bit in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xev:

```
sudo apt-get install xev
```

Open a terminal, and run xev from the command line. Put your mouse in the window that just opened, and click one of your mouse's buttons. You will get a lot of output for every click. Find a block that looks like this, the most important part being near the end (button 3 in this case):

```
ButtonPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001, root 0x269, subw 0x3c00002, time 14058208, (44,38), root:(1725,240), state 0x10, button 3, same_screen YES
```

Try all your buttons and find the order you want them. Run xinput and try the result. In my case it was:

```
xinput -set-button-map "Evoluent VerticalMouse 4" 1 3 9 4 5 6 7 8 2 10
```

Put the xinput command in a file in your home directory. To run it at each startup, add it to the startup command list of your OS. Run a search for "startup" or "startup applications" from the home menu, you should find it easily. Just tried with Xubuntu 14.04, and it took 3 seconds to find.

Source: https://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2013/07/16/advanced-linux-mouse-configuration-made-easy/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  After many hours of trying to use code to make the switch from left to right permanent, I found a simple answer.  Navigate to System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad.  Open that folder and there you have it--choose your primary button to be right or left simply by checking the radio button of your choice.  That choice will stay with you until you change it.  No more losing it after rebooting.  It made my day!