# How can I decrease the volume increment in 14.04?

Tags: unity, sound, configuration

I know that this has already been asked a lot, but all solutions that I found are old, pre - Unity. So, I am asking again: How can I decrease the sound increment(or decrement) that happens when the mouse wheel is scrolled, if the cursor is hovering over the volume bar(like shown below)?

[image]

Comment: Is the Ctrl+ Ctrl- just when you're hovering over the volume indicator, or is that all the time? If it is all the time, that will interfere with zoom.

Comment: Ops, sorry, I got it wrong. I meant alt+ and alt-, which is a shortcut that I made. My bad. Forget about this shortcut thing.

Comment: This should be possible, but I think it depends partly on your screen size, and what other apps are open in the status bar.

Comment: @Tim my screen size? Why? I don't get it.

Comment: you might want to take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/507230/finer-volume-control-in-14-04

Answer (score 0):

You should control your volume either my mouse scroll as you suggested or by left/right arrow keys.

If arrow keys aren't working, then it's probably a bug described at [indicator-sound keyboard controls with left/right ARROW keys broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ido/+bug/1242550).

This bug was fixed in the package ido - 13.10.0+14.04.20140213-0ubuntu1.

If the volume adjust is too coarse-grained, try upgrading indicator-sound package (>= 0.5.6) or try to [Decrease mouse sensitivity below the standard limit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8506/decrease-mouse-sensitivity-below-the-standard-limit).

Alternatively you can define your own keyboard shortcuts in System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts. As a side note you must have the correct sound mixer device selected in System->Preferences->Sound for it to work properly. This may be a problem source if your volume will not adjust.

Comment: My indicator-sound is 12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1. And everything is working fine, I just want to decrease the volume increment.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the sensitivity of the mouse scroll wheel? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8506/decrease-mouse-sensitivity-below-the-standard-limit