# Finer volume control in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, volume-control

In 14.04, the volume slider (controlled by HW switch) seems to move in very large jumps: for instance, from

> [image]

to

> [image]

in a single keystroke. Sorry about the tricky screenshot, but that looks like almost a "10%" increase in volume. **How can I control volume more finely, i.e. increase in smaller increments?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to System Settings and click keyboard.

[image]

Click Shortcuts, and custom shortcuts.

[image]

Click add and then enter into it the following:

```
Volume+

amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
```

[image]

Click save and then repeat for Volume- (change the `5%+` to `5%-`)

Click on disabled, then press the appropriate volume key. It will say `Do you want to reassign`. Click yes. Do the same for Volume-.

[image]

If it is too much of an increase, change it to `2%+` rather than `5%+`

Comment: [I did the key binding to those commands](http://i.imgur.com/IuM8S8M.png), but even though [this](http://i.imgur.com/nQtwZXh.png) works, the volume still does not change when I press the volume keys.

Comment: Thats odd... Does it work if you assign `Super`+`=` or `Super`+`-`?

Comment: Yes. Does it matter that my volume key is the Fn-F12/11 kind?

Comment: Possibly... I ended up using Super+= and Super+- on my old laptop, you do get used to it. You could just use the FX keys, i recommend F3+F4 or F7+F8, they're less often used in applications.

Comment: By the way, those screenshots are beautiful. How did you do them?

Comment: Alt+Print Screen (look in the screenshots section of the above window) , then the red boxes are drawn on in inkscape, it has lovely rounded rectangles! To get a menu, you have to use Print Screen. I also cheat for unity, I use a Virtual Machine, it makes some things easier!

Comment: The only side effect, which could be a downside for some people, is that the volume slider is no longer shown with this alteration.